# PIC Curiosity HPC with multiple UARTs

Tags: pic, uart, mplabx, mplab, dev-kit

I've got a Curiously HPC with two mikroBUS UART modules fitted (1x FTDI232R and 1x RS485 5V), however MCC in MPLAB X isn't letting me map the EUSART2 of the target (PIC18F46K40) to module 2, even though the Curiously HPC schematic shows as having a RX and TX on both mikroBUS module connectors.

[image]

It'll let me map ESUART2 to Port B or Pord D, however TX and RX go to Port C on the Curiousy schematic.

[image]

Am i missing something or is it just not possible?

Comment: You are not missing anything. Microchip, in their infinite and near God like wisdom, made it impossible to configure both mikroBUS click sites to use both UARTS in a 40-pin PIC18F46K40 with only the solder blob jumpers. You can do this with a 28-pin PIC18F26K40 and the DM164136 HPC board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible witout rewiring the HPC board as @Dan1138 suggested.